# can an outside spot light block visibility into house window at night

Tags: windows, exterior, light

I have 4 very large windows in the front of my house that currently have no window covering. I want to tint these windows for privacy but when I have my lights on at night people will still be able to clearly see inside.  So I had the idea of using spot lights at night to counter the light from inside my house... could this possibly work and if so any ideas of what kind of lights would be needed and would I shine the light directly at the window?
thanks

Comment: Get some black plastic and masking tape. Your solution is questionable and impractical.

Comment: Study how lighting works and stuff will make a lot more sense.  Lighting the windows from outside will only work if there's some sort of scrim, blind or surface treatment to illuminate when lit up from the outside, so the peeping tom would see the scrim instead of the occupants. Of course it would illuminate inside the house too, which would be annoying.  Or you could aim the light straight *outward* under the guise of lighting up your yard, but actually throwing light in the eyes of the peeping toms.

Answer (score 2):

You'll get some reflection off the glass that will make it more difficult to see inside, but you'll have to try it so see whether it works as well as you hope.  The downside is that you'll have bright spotlights shining in through your windows, which will make you feel like you're on stage all the time.  My guess is that you'd end up installing blinds or curtains to block the spotlights.

Comment: You'd want lights coming at the glass from several angles, otherwise only one side would be obscured.

Answer (score 0):

Short-term, blinds/curtains/similar. Even something that's essentially sheer(?) would block outside-in visibility.

Long term, why not trees? Something leafy would have a much more appealing look in general, from inside and out.